# Run 2 variables in loop where value of one is larger

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, range

How can I run loop where I need 2 variables with range where value of 1 variable is larger than other.
For example

```
x = 3
y = 4

for x_val, y_val in zip(range(x), range(y)):
    print(x_val)
    print(y_val)
```

I want `y` to run 4 times and not stop at 3 because x value is 3.

Note - this is an simplified example of the thing I need. I know we can print x_val only and not need y_val. But I want have 2 variables(x_val, y_val) based on looping variables for different functions.

Comment: what is the output you want exactly

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat ```1 1 2 2 3 3 4``` <- (here <space> is next line)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `izip_longest` in python2 and [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) for python3.

```
from itertools import zip_longest
x = 3
y = 7

for x_val, y_val in zip_longest(range(x), range(y),fillvalue=' '):
    print(x_val)
    print(y_val)
```

> *If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in with fillvalue. Iteration continues until the longest iterable is exhausted.*

EDIT:

`fillvalue` to be largest iterable's last value.

```
x=3
y=4
for x,y in zip_longest(range(x),range(y),fillvalue=range(x)[-1] if x>y else range(y)[-1]):
    print(x,y)
```

---

output:

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
6 3
6 4
6 5
6 6
```

Comment: @codekls I didn't get you. May be a example would help me understand better. Provide input and expected output.

Comment: This worked however is there a way to continue printing ```y_value``` depending on y range instead of fillvalue which assigns a specific value to the variable after the 1st variable ```(x)``` has ended and runs 1 time only.

Comment: If I understood correctly you want printing the last element of range instead of specific fillvalue? @codekls

Comment: @Ch3esteR yes but not just the last element as y could be 5 so I need it to print ```4 5```.

Answer (score 0):

zip is what is causing your iterations to stop at 3. By default it stops at the shortest range.

Answer (score 0):

the problem  is on function ZIP because by default is stops  at the shortest range.So at x = 3 .
But u can solve the problem by  importing and using this module  izip_longest